# Fade in image when adding it to HTML5 canvas - Processing time concern

Tags: html5-canvas

I am using the HTML5 canvas to draw an organisational structure. Each node includes an image, the URL of which is obtained form a database. I have a little function that handles the loading of the image, and that adds it to the canvas once loaded. It looks like this (note that the important bit is the onload listener added to the image):

```
(function (i, ctx, DrawId) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = REPORT.Structures[i].Managers[j].Employee.PhotoUrl; //get URL from object constructed elsewhere      
    img.onload = function () { //attach onload event          
            ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);//draw image on the canvas. x, y width and height are calculated inside the onload, but I have removed the calculations to improve readability
        }
    }
})(i, ctx, REPORT.DrawId);
```

This works great, except that the images all pop into existence at random as they finish loading. It looks very untidy.

I am looking for a way to make this look smoother. My first instinct is to try and create a fade in effect, but I can't think of how to do this without redrawing the canvas over and over.

I have thought of trying something like this:

```
img.onload = function () {
    var counter = 1;
    var width = 30 * REPORT.ZoomLevel;
    var height = 30 * REPORT.ZoomLevel;
    function fadeInImage(ctx, img, x, y, width, height) {
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1 * counter;
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
        counter++;
        if (counter == 10)
            clearTimeout(fadeInImageTimeout);
        console.log(counter);
    }
    var fadeInImageTimeout = setInterval(function () { fadeInImage(ctx, img, x, y, width, height); }, 100);
}
```

This works, but I am also worried that if it does, it will be too processing heavy.

Has anyone tried doing something like this? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

PS:
I am currently considering only having one interval that draws all images. Each image will be pushed into an array, and all elements in the array will be drawn once all images are loaded. Will keep you updated.

PPS:
I have managed to get it working as I mentioned in the PS above. It does not seem to affect the performance though. I guess the lag I am still experiencing is related to the image loading time. I'll try and strip out the code into a bare bones version and post it here a bit later, but if anyone can see a flaw in my approach, please do not hesitate to point it out. Again, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: part of the problem is that you are declaring multiple local copies of `fadeInImage`, one for each `img` you load.

Comment: what if you preload the images and keep it hidden, and when the canvas starts you begin to place each image at it's position